# How to create a .NET Core Serializer for indented Javascript objects

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to serialize JSON objects received from an API in a cli app. I'm having issues understanding how to create the objects in .NET for JSON objects which have an indented structure.

For example, this is fine:

```
{"status": "ok" }

public class Success
{
    public string status { get; set; }
}
```

But something like this is where I'm stuck and both of the examples from the below return null when the client API receives them.

```
[
  {
    "id": "some_uuid_string_1", 
    "message": "hello"
  }, 
  {
    "id": "some_uuid_string_2", 
    "message": "world"
  }
]
```

Attempted solution

```
public class Received

{
    public Dictionary<string,string> received { get; set; }
}
```

Alternatively I also tried a simpler structure, leaving out the explicit names and just using the IDs and values, which is closer to what my app requires and lets me make smaller requests.

```
{
  "some_uuid_string_1": "hello", 
  "some_uuid_string_2": "world"
}
```

For this example I tried this, a list of key value pairs in the form of a dictionary.

```
public class Message
{
    public Dictionary<string,string> message { get; set; }
}

public class Received
{
    public List<Message> received { get; set; }
}
```

How can I create objects in C# for these two structures? One indented with set names and one 'generic' with no set names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
}

[
  {
    "id": "some_uuid_string", 
    "message": "hello"
  }, 
  {
    "id": "some_uuid_string", 
    "message": "world"
  }
]
```

Deserializes to a `List<MyClass>` or `MyClass[]`

---

```
{
  "some_uuid_string_1": "hello", 
  "some_uuid_string_2": "world"
}
```

Deserializes to

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string some_uuid_string_1 { get; set; }
    public string some_uuid_string_2 { get; set; }
}
```

or `Dictionary<string, string>`

---

The reason your `Received` class solution didn't work is because it is expecting a `JSON` property of `received`, as your class has a property named `received`, but the `JSON` does not.

This is the same issue with your `Message` class. Your class has property `message` whereas your `JSON` does not.

Comment: No duplication, I edited the post to show

Answer (score 0):

create a class

```
public class MessageId
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
}
```

you can deserialize your json

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var messages=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MessageId>>(yourJson);
```